# How is extending an interface legal in Java?

Tags: java

`Comparable` is defined as an interface. In that case, why is `Key K extends Comparable<K>` legal in the following case, and why isn't `K implements Comparable<K>` used instead?

```
public class Entry<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Entry<K, V>> { ... }
```

This kind of code is used in ordered symbol tables for example.

Comment: because you are not extending the interface, you are defining, by generics, that the value `K` needs to be a subclass of Comperable.

Comment: buy why is it not sufficient for the K to just implement Comparable by overriding compareTo?

Comment: @JitendraKulkarni: The type argument provided for `K` *can* be a class implementing `Comparable<K>`... or it could be another interface.

Comment: It is legal because the JLS says is it is.  The alternative is illegal because the JLS says it is.  It is defined this way because that's how the Java designers decided to design it.  They probably had good reasons, but that is moot.  In fact, unless you are planning on implementing your own (Java like) language, questions like this are moot.

Comment: @Stephen C: I would rather understand why I am typing something that is looking odd than typing it because someone arbitrarily decided it. See Jon's and Makoto's  answer that provided a clue about why they might have decided that way. Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Makoto: Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `K` could be an interface extending `Comparable<K>` instead of a class implementing it... in which case `extends` would be more suitable. As the declaration of `Entry` doesn't *know* whether `K` will be an interface type or a class type, it can't be right in every situation.

Ultimately this just gives simple and consistent syntax for expressing generic bounds without having to worry whether that upper bound is a class or an interface.

Answer (score 3):

[Because "extends" in this context is different.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

> Note that, in this context, `extends` is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

This is one of the other nuances of generics; the keywords `extends` and `super` play very distinct roles, which are very specific to generics.  In this scenario, `extends` represents an upper bound; you're guaranteed that `K` will be *at most* a `Comparable`.

[The Java Trails tutorial on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) provides tons of further context into this.